# SQL SUM Query Modification

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a SUM SQL query that is being used to display a chart in asp.net.

It sums up the amount of quantities that have the same value for example:

```
   Quantity|Total
   --------|-----
       1   | 5
       2   | 10
       3   | 12
       4   | 16
       5   | 5
       6   | 8
```

Basicaly, there are 5 orders where quantity = 1, there are 10 orders where quantity = 2 and so on.

```
 SELECT        Quantity, SUM(Quantity) AS Total
 FROM            orders
 GROUP BY Quantity
```

Thats my code for that.

I wanna know how i can make the query so i get this result.

```
   Quantity|Total
   --------|-----
       1   | 5
       2   | 10
       3   | 12
       4   | 16
       5   | 5
       6   | 8
       6+  | 5
```

So every order that has quantity over 6, they should be added together and displayed like 
                       **6+  | 5**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` and your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Quantity > 6 THEN '6+' ELSE CAST(Quantity AS CHAR(2)) END AS Quantity, 
        SUM(Quantity) AS Total
FROM    orders
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Quantity > 6 THEN '6+' ELSE CAST(Quantity AS CHAR(2)) END;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d568b/3)**

---

N.B. Based in this statement:

> Basicaly, there are 5 orders where quantity = 1, there are 10 orders where quantity = 2 and so on.

And you expected results, it sounds like you want to use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`, since if there are 10 orders were quantity = 2, then `SUM(Quantity)` will yield 20, not 10 as you have indicated in the results.

**[Revised Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58bae/2)**

Comment: works like a charm, thank you. I knew i had to use CASE just didnt know where to start.